# Excel formula for just M-F and T-S of each month

Tags: excel, validation, date, formula

I have to build a report that has two different date columns in it; M-F of the previous month, and T-S of the previous month.

If in column A I have a list of all days from the previous month

```
         A
1  |  8/1/2013  |
2  |  8/2/2013  |
       ...
31 |  8/31/2013 |
```

Is there a formula that could be used in columns B and C to get the necessary dates?

Comment: This does work for M-F with the exception of when it finds a weekend, it has a blank cell. Is there a way to eliminate all these blanks in the column without any special formatting? Meaning, is there a way that next month I can just change 1 date list, and have the rest flal into place?

Comment: Above comment. It places empty spaces (which makes sense given the formula), but for the dates to be used in the report, there needs to be no empty cells

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Well, sure, you can use this formula to avoid the blank cells in between the dates:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$31,SMALL(IF(MOD($A$1:$A$31,7)>1,ROW($A$1:$A$31,9^99),ROW())),"")`

This formula (for Monday to Friday) needs to be called with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. After doing this for the first date, you can drag down to the bottom.

For the one with Tuesday to Saturday, it's a bit longer;

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$31,SMALL(IF(((MOD($A$1:$A$31,7)>2)+(MOD($A$1:$A$31,7)=0))>0,ROW($A$1:$A$31),9^99),ROW())),"")`

But at the same time, you have to call this function with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> as otherwise, you won't be able to get the other dates (you will get `#NUM!` instead for the other dates).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of typing the days in column A, you could do something like this:

[image: Previous Month's Days of Week]

In cell B1 is this formula (formatted as m/d/yyyy):

```
=TODAY()
```

In cell B2 is this formula (formatted as mmmm):

```
=DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1)-1,1)
```

In cell A5 is this formula (formatted as m/d/yyyy):

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(B2,2)<6,B2,B2+1+(WEEKDAY(B2+1,2)>5))
```

In cell A6 and copied down to A37 is this formula (formatted as m/d/yyyy):

```
=IF(NETWORKDAYS(B$2,EOMONTH(B$2,0))>COUNT(A$5:A5),A5+1+2*(WEEKDAY(A5+1,2)>5),"")
```

In cell B5 is this formula (formatted as m/d/yyyy):

```
=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A5,2)<>{1,7}),B2,B2+1+(OR(WEEKDAY(B2+1,2)={1,7})))
```

Lastly, in cell B6 copied down to B37 is this formula (formatted as m/d/yyyy):

```
=IF(B5="","",IF(MONTH(B5+1+OR(WEEKDAY(B5+1,2)={1,7})*2)<>MONTH(B$2),"",B5+1+OR(WEEKDAY(B5+1,2)={1,7})*2))
```

Now the M-F and T-S dates will automatically update whenever you enter a new month.  If you'd prefer to manually control it, you can just type in the date of a month in cell B1, like 8/1/2013.  Then the formulas will take care of the rest and will bring in the appropriate dates from July.

Comment: shouldn't 1st August 2013 also be in the **TS** list?

Comment: You are correct, I didn't think about that in initial response. I have edited the answer to account for it.  Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WORKDAY` function for this:

Given that you already have 1st of the previous month in A1 put this formula in B1

`=WORKDAY(A$1-1,1)`

.....and this one in C1

`=WORKDAY(A$1-2,1)+1`

then in B2....

`=IF(B1="","",IF(MONTH(WORKDAY(B1,1))=MONTH(A$1),WORKDAY(B1,1),""))`

and in C2

`=IF(B1="","",IF(MONTH(WORKDAY(B1-1,1)+1)=MONTH(A$1),WORKDAY(B1-1,1)+1,""))`

and copy those latter two formulas down to row 23

When there are fewer than 23 **MF** days or **TS** days in the month the lowest cells will display as blanks.

If you want to exclude listed holiday dates you can also do that with WORKDAY